# Overcharging car battery

Tags: battery

I've had a decent amount of corrosion on positive side of battery post/cable.  Twice in last couple of months. Could it be due to hooking up too many accessories to power outlet in cab, or something else?

Comment: Have you put anything on the terminals after cleaning them to prevent corrosion? Grease works really well.

Answer (score 3):

Extra accessories are unlikely to be a cause.

The corrosion is caused by acid mist escaping from the battery. it could be normal, or could be a sign of a faulty regulator in/on the altenator.

Check that the battery voltage, and electrolyte levels are normal.

Answer (score 0):

I find a petroleum based jelly - vaseline works better for battery terminals to reduce corrosion compared to an ordinary grease. Having a tub in my tool box caused many mechanics to make dodgy jokes about why I needed that...